# Variable scope in C

Tags: c, variables

I have a main() function and prior to declaring main(), I declare global variables.

Then inside main() 2 processes start: 1 child and 1 parent via fork(). Why can't the parent and child processes share the global variables I declared? What is a good way to handle this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `fork()` you're spawning a new process. Everything *at the time of the fork* is copied, but after that ... nothing is shared.

You have two choices at that point:

- Keep a pipe open between your two processes and communicate changes
- Re-write your code to be multi-threaded, where you can access the same data (using locks)

Comment: Thanks. So the only good way to share data between them would be via a common file?

Comment: No, there's plenty of other options, shared memory, pipes, etc.

Comment: There's actually another way that involves shared memory, but that's really overkill in most cases (and complicated). A file may be sufficient depending on what you're trying to do, but you will want to look at `flock()` to make sure you're not writing to the file at the same time.

Comment: @user629034 - A pipe is like a file that isn't written to the disk. One process keeps the read end of the pipe and reads from it, and the other keeps the write end and writes to it, allowing them to communicate through a "file" without the speedbump of disk IO.

Comment: @paxdiablo - I said pipe :)  You could use middleware too, but that's prob beyond the scope of this.

Comment: @Brian, that you did. I just didn't see it. +1.

Comment: @user629034: read [Beej's Guide to Unix Interprocess Communication](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/).

Answer (score 0):

With fork() you create a new process with separate memory space. To communicate between processes you can use signals (using kill())

If you want to share variables, consider using threads (e.g. pthread.h). Then you can use events or mutexes for thread synchronization.